# Laravel dompdf not showing japanese characters

Tags: laravel, utf-8, dompdf

I am using Laravel 5.4 and barryvdh/laravel-dompdf plugin for dompdf. I am using this code,

**Controller**

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice');
```

**View** (invoice.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>빨간색</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When using this code the japanese text will not show correctly. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this link](http://reffect.co.jp/blog/post/laravel-dompdf70-japanese) for the answer. It is in japanese but you can use google chrome translate.

In Summary:

1. Download font file from http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/old/ipafont/download.html or use any ttf files you want
2. Download load_font.php file from https://github.com/dompdf/utils to /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/
3. execute `#php load_font.php ipag $path_to_font_directory/ipag.tt` which will generate something like

> Unable to find bold face file.
>       Unable to find italic face file.
>       Unable to find bold_italic face file.
>       Copying $path_to_font_directory/ ipag.ttf to $laravel_install_directory /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/ipag.ttf...
>       Generating Adobe Font Metrics for $laravel_install_directory /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/ipag...

4. Copy font files to storage #cp  lib/fonts/* /storage/fonts/
5. Reference your font in css

```html
body {
font-family: ipag;
}
```